# Not understanding this ssh forwarding buisness

Tags: git, github, ssh

So I followed, or thought that I followed: [githubs tut on ssh forwarding](https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/) and came running into into some issues.

When I did: `ssh -v mysiteName.com`

I got the issue where it was asking me for:

```
Adam@mysiteName.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

There is no user named Adam on my server, which is managed by me and me only. I am not sure why it is using the user name of my mac and trying to access my site with it. It should be `UserName@mysiteName.com's`, not Adam (obvi UserName is a mask for the real user name)

I went into `~/.ssh/config` and see:

```
Host mySiteName.com                                                                                                                                                                      
  ForwardAgent yes
```

And in the `/etc/ssh_config` I see:

```
Host *
  SendEnv LANG LC_*
  ForwardAgent yes
```

So that part is all good and when I do `ssh-agent -L` I see my key. So I can assume that part is good.

On my server I do:

```
echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
/tmp/ssh-1RgQijAj2U/agent.14798
```

So that part works, the last part that doesn't work is:

```
git clone my_github_repo
Cloning into 'Git-Repo-Name'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

So my questions are as follows:

- **Whats with the Adam@siteName.com's password? It should be UserName@siteNames.com**
- **Whats with the failed ssh agent forwarding? My mac is forwarding this key to this server, the key is there why is failing to clone a repo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` uses by default your current username. If you want to use another, specify it to `ssh` with `-l` (`ssh -l user mysiteName.com`) option or with the url (`ssh user@mysiteName.com`). If you still have issues using your ssh key, come back and give us some logs info from server and client.